# Sublime Text 2: Which scope is used for autocomplete?

Tags: autocomplete, latex, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, markdown

I use an `include` rule in `Markdown.tmLanguage` to get some LaTeX syntax highlighting for LaTeX environments in Markdown files.

```
"tex_environments": {
        "name": "markup.raw.inline.markdown",
        "comment": "TeX Environments",
        "begin": "\\\\begin\\{[^\\}]*\\}",
        "end": "\\\\end\\{[^\\}]*\\}",
        "patterns": [
            { "include": "text.tex.latex" }
        ]
    }
```

Inside these environments I still get HTML autocompletion. The `Scope Hunter` plugin shows the following scopes:

```
text.html.markdown
meta.paragraph.markdown
markup.raw.inline.markdown
```

I assume that the first scope determines the language for autocompletion? Can I convince Sublime that I want LaTeX autocompletion?